# PHP database related error, and MySQL error

Tags: php, mysql

This is the error I receive when I type in code further down:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order(order_date,cust_firstname,cust_lastname,cust_add,cust_city,cust_state,indi' at line 1

The code for this error is:

```
<?php
include "db.php";
    $cust_firstname=$_POST['name'];
    $cust_lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
    $cust_add=$_POST['add'];
    $cust_city=$_POST['city'];
    $cust_state=$_POST['state'];
    $cust_country=$_POST['country'];
    $cust_zip=$_POST['pincode'];
    $cust_phone=$_POST['mobile'];
    $cust_email=$_POST['email'];
    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO order(order_date,cust_firstname,cust_lastname,cust_add,cust_city,cust_state,$cust_country,cust_zip,cust_phone,cust_email)values(now(),'$cust_firstname','$cust_lastname','$cust_add','$cust_city','$cust_state','$cust_country','$cust_zip','$cust_phone','$cust_email')")or die(mysql_error());
    header("location:done.php");
?>
```

What I'm wondering, is what this error really means and what I have to do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html). You need to wrap it in ticks:

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `order` (order_date,
```

Comment: You deserve an upvote for correctly saying why and linking to reserved words. ^^

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `order` (order_date,cu.....
```

`order` is reserved key word in mysql

EDIT:

change this

```
   $cust_country
```

to

```
   cust_country
```

in insert statment columns